# Smarty not working on smart phone touch

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to figure out why this script works on a desktop and not on a touchscreen smart phone. It keeps reloading itself on a phone.

```
<p class="payment_module">  
<form id="aut" name="pesapal_form" action="{$module_dir}payment.php" method="post">
    {foreach from=$p key=k item=v}
    <input type="hidden" name="{$k}" value="{$v}" />
    {/foreach}
    <input type="image" value="{l s='Validate order' mod='pesapal'}" src="{$base_dir_ssl}modules/pesapal/logo_pesapal.jpg" border="0" style="border:0" />
</form>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you trying to launch your php application on smart phone?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it reloading itself - Smarty is a server side language so it wouldn't affect client side. The issue is likely to be with your Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it is a checkout system logo for a shopping cart that is supposed to summon payment.php. like i said, it works fine with a mouse and not touch screen.

Comment: `works fine with a mouse and not touch screen` You mean you can't submit via touch? Anyway it's something client side